# How to send auth token in feathersjs via post to rest service?

Tags: feathersjs

I am working through learning feathers and I am trying to send some data to a service I created.  It works fine when I use it without any authorization.  When I add authorization I can send the JWT token manually with postman.  However when I send a post I am not sure how to send the token in the header or the best way to handle this.  The example I have found uses socket.io.  Is there a way to do this with a simple post?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
  <title>Feathers Chat</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.rawgit.com/feathersjs/feathers-chat/v0.1.0/public/base.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.rawgit.com/feathersjs/feathers-chat/v0.1.0/public/chat.css">
</head>
<body>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//unpkg.com/feathers-client@^1.0.0/dist/feathers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var host = 'http://localhost:3030';
  // Set up Feathers client side
  var app = feathers()
    .configure(feathers.rest(host).jquery(jQuery))
    .configure(feathers.hooks())
    .configure(feathers.authentication({ storage: window.localStorage }));
  // authenticate using your JWT that was passed in the short lived cookie
  app.authenticate().then(function(result){
    console.log('Authenticated!', result);
    alert('Your JWT is: ' + app.get('token'));
  }).catch(function(error){
    console.error('Error authenticating!', error);
  });
</script>

<main class="login container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-6-tablet push-3-tablet text-center">
      <h1 class="font-100">Post</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-6-tablet push-3-tablet col-4-desktop push-4-desktop text-center">
      <form class="form" method="post" action="/posts">
        <fieldset>
          <input class="block" type="text" name="title" placeholder="title">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <input class="block" type="text" name="description" placeholder="description">
        </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" class="button button-primary block login">
          Post
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help! I really like feathers so far.

Comment: The example you posted seems to be using REST with jQuery (which does the POST internally when calling `app.authenticate` and then sends the token with every subsequent request). Isn't that what you would like to do?

Comment: I have no trouble receiving the token from authenticating.  My question is do I need to do something like this with jQuery when I do a post to my feathers service and create a header with the auth token that was supplied?  something like this? $.ajax({
   url : myurl,
   headers: {
        ‘Authorization’ : token
   });

Comment: If you are not using the client, yes. But I don't see why you would want to do that since you already have the client set up. The client allows you to transparently use all services without having to worry about going through jQuery AJAX manually.

Comment: Ahh ok thanks for the info.  I will review my code and see where I have a bug.  Good to know it should handle this for me.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this is what I did and seems to work fine.  I wasn't sure if feathers was somehow automagically handling the auth token after it was created.  Once I setup the post to send via jquery and setup the authorization header it worked fine.  Thanks for all the help.  I do like feathers a lot so far!

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".test-form" ).submit(function( event ) {
var token =  app.get('token');

    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:3030/posts/',
      type: 'post',
      data: {
      title: $("#title").val(),
        description: $("#description").val()
      },
      headers: {
        Authorization: token
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        console.info(data);
      }
    });
  });});
```

Comment: While this technically works, it's not the way Feathers is meant to be used. Feathers has a client-side library to handle these things. I submitted an answer because I can't get syntax highlighting in a comment, make sure to check it out :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/39535755/2781915

Answer (score 1):

Use the Feathers client. The same `app` you're using to do authentication.

```js
// Get the Posts service to work with
var postsService = app.service('posts');

// Create a post
postsService.create({
    title: $('#title').val(),
    description: $('#description').val()
});

// Do something when a Post is created
postsService.on('created', function (post) {
    // `post` is the newly created post
    // this callback will run whenever a post is created
    console.log(post);
});
```

You could even use the `postsService.create` method in an event handler, something like…

```js
$('form').on('submit', function () {
    postsService.create({
        title: $('#title').val(),
        description: $('#description').val()
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this section: http://docs.feathersjs.com/authentication/client.html

You can get token with `app.get('token')`.

Comment: Yes thanks for your response.  I already use the app.get('token') in the code I posted above.  I have no trouble logging in and retrieving my token via the authentication in feathersjs.  My trouble comes with how to use this token for authentication directly with my services with rest via a form post.  In the examples in the documentation, I only see examples which use websockets and don't see a rest example.  Do you have to use sockets when connecting to your services or can authentication be done via rest?  Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 0):

when you post the data, set the header field in **Authorization -> token** which you get when you login.

[image]